# How to move specific column one row up?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have the following text file:

```
 ...                .....               .....              .......

 Ca28               0.97222484          7.48500210         18.99362895

 Ca30               1.78544464          4.99000140          3.81528863

 Ca32               7.93680381          4.99000140          9.88662475

 Co1                1.67818190          3.65539564         25.52346192

 Co2                1.67818190          8.64539704         25.52346192

 C2                 5.91285159          2.49500070          9.88662475

 O2                 6.70274792          1.85423438         10.66624532

 O4                 4.75829822          1.85423438         16.73758145

 ..                 .....               ....               ....
```

I wonder how to move with `awk` the first column one row up to obtain:

```
 ... 
           .....               .....              .......

 Ca28
           0.97222484          7.48500210         18.99362895

 Ca30  
           1.78544464          4.99000140          3.81528863

 Ca32   
           7.93680381          4.99000140          9.88662475

 Co1  
           1.67818190          3.65539564         25.52346192

 Co2
           1.67818190          8.64539704         25.52346192

 C2     
           5.91285159          2.49500070          9.88662475

 O2     
           6.70274792          1.85423438         10.66624532

 O4        
           4.75829822          1.85423438         16.73758145
 ..   
           .....               ....               ....
```

I asked before to do the inverse with `awk 'NR%2!=0{prev=$0;next} {print prev, $0}' file` but now I don't know how to do that with the same code.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you REALLY have a blank line between every data line of your input?

Comment: @Ed Morton It doesn't really matter, but with the sat solution is enought.

Comment: yes, it does matter, but if you're happy with the solution you have and fully understand what the impact will be of executing it (it will NOT, for example, produce the output you say you want from the input file you posted), then enough said.

Comment: @Ed Morton You are right, sorry about that, I'm not a native english speaker so I can be missunderstood. Apologise.

Comment: No problem and language isn't the real issue, it's that you posted input and output that don't reflect your real data. Just make sure you post accurate, testable input and output in future and if you'd be happy with output other than what you post, just say that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk '{ $1 = $1 RS }1' yourfile
```

**Explanation:**

`RS` - Record Separator. `\n` is awk default value.

`1`  - prints `$0`(whole line)

Comment: Thank you again sat. You are the boss :)